# Не вставляется стилизованная google map в страницу wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api

Не отображается google map на странице сайта wordpress, консоль выдает:

> You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.

Пробовал подключить в хедере и в теле страницы

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDF7Dz_OP6Vo64R8HTepLroHLOPdfx-9Gg&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

И в **functions.php**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvNUt5RMPIkktufWNUFCp0_JkWfSRvTdU&sensor=false' );
```

Безрезультатно.
Выводится на страницу карта как контейнер с id

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Переведите ошибку, написано что вы несколько раз подключили апи. Проверьте на сайте сгенерированный хтмл и посмотрите где лишний раз вставляется

Comment: Апи был подключен один раз, после пробовал вставить карту через плагин, подобной ошибки не возникало

Comment: Это вам кажется, что он был подключен один раз. Откройте исходный код страницы через Ctrl+U, нажмите Ctrl+F, введите maps.googleapis.com и посмотрите количество результатов.

Comment: Похоже, конфликтует с одним подключенным к форме на то

Comment: й же странице скриптом